# How to Load Plist to UITableView Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist, tableview

I have this plist setup:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <array>
            <dict>
                    <key>area</key>
                    <string>area1</string>
                    <key>shop</key>
                    <string>shop1</string>
                    <key>location</key>
                    <string>2nd Floor</string>
                    <key>coordinates</key>
                    <string>14.733836,121.058221</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                    <key>area</key>
                    <string>area1</string>
                    <key>shop</key>
                    <string>shop2</string>
                    <key>location</key>
                    <string>Ground Floor</string>
                    <key>coordinates</key>
                    <string>14.733836,121.058221</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                    <key>area</key>
                    <string>area2</string>
                    <key>shop</key>
                    <string>shop1</string>
                    <key>location</key>
                    <string>2nd Floor</string>
                    <key>coordinates</key>
                    <string>14.656918,121.029795</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                    <key>area</key>
                    <string>area2</string>
                    <key>shop</key>
                    <string>shop2</string>
                    <key>location</key>
                    <string>Ground Floor</string>
                    <key>coordinates</key>
                    <string>14.656918,121.029795</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        </plist>
```

How can I plot this inside my UITableView? My header titles will be the key "area" while the table cell labels the key "shop" and the subtitle labels the key "location". The coordinates key will be used to plot it on the mapview that loads when the user taps the table cell.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
cell.textLabel.text = [dict objectForKey: @"shop"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey: @"location"];

- (NSString *)tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
NSString *area = [dict objectForKey: @"area"];
return area;

- (void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
NSString *coordinates = [dict objectForKey: @"coordinates"];
newViewController.coordinates = coordinates
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 3 NSDictionary.
Dict 1: titles
Dict 2: celltexts
Dict 3: subtitles

NSDictionary *dictTitles = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"filepathtoyourplist"] valueForKey:@"Titles"];

Then put it into an array

NSArray *titleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithDictionary:dictTitles];

in your titlesForHeaderInSection

headertitle = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Do the steps for cell text and subtitle again.

Comment: The idea behind it works, you just have to code it correctly ;) NSDictionary is the way to work with PLISTS

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm getting an error in creating the NSArray. It says No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'initWithDictionary'.

Comment: Hm let me check it on my Mac whats available

Comment: NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@""] valueForKey:@""];
    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"titles"]; there you go :) this works

Comment: Is valueForKey in dict really blank?

Comment: No :) I just gave you an example. you have to put YOUR plist key in it ;)

Comment: I did everything. Here's my codes. `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *areaDict; @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *areaArray; self.areaDict = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestLoc" ofType:@"plist"]] valueForKey:@"area"]; NSLog(@"Dict is: %@", self.areaDict); self.areaArray = [self.areaDict objectForKey:@"area"]; NSLog(@"Array is: %@", self.areaArray);` All logs return null. Am I missing something?

Comment: lol what you are trying to do with the NSLog? you can do: NSLog(@"Count: %d",self.areaDict.count); but what you try is NSLog the Dictionary which will return NULL.

Comment: Haha! Apologies for that. Nevertheless, even without the logs, the table doesn't return any values.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
//In your .h file
NSArray *array;

//In your .m file
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
   // Some code...
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"plist"];
   array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
   // Some code...
}
```

Then you create a new NSObject class and for each cell you init your object, for example :

```
MyClass *newInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
newInstance.area = [array objectForKey:@"area"];
newInstance.shop = [array objectForKey:@"shop"];
newInstance.location = [array objectForKey:@"location"];
newInstance.coordinates = [array objectForKey:@"coordinates"];
```

Hope it helps :)